# Getting SQLite no such column

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

this is my database, can you please help me with it? i think there is nothing wrong i tried reinstalling the app to update the database initially but still doesnt work. it says that there is no such column _url.

This is my class that creates the database:

MySQLiteHelper.java

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /**
     * table for locations
     * | _id | _latitude | _longitude | _time | _provider
     */ 
    public static final String TABLE_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "_latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "_longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCURACY = "_accuracy";
    public static final String COLUMN_PROVIDER = "_provider";


    /**
     * table for pictures
     * | _id | _url | _latitude | _longitude | _time
     */ 
    public static final String TABLE_PICTURE = "picture";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_URL = "_url";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_LATITUDE = "_latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_LONGITUDE = "_longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_TIME = "_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_PIC_ACCURACY = "_accuracy";

    /**
     * table for Accelerometer
     * | _id | _x | _y | _z | _time
     */ 
    public static final String TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "accelerometer";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X = "_x";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y = "_y";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z = "_z";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME = "_time";

    /**
     * table for Sound
     * | _id | _amplitude | _time
     */ 
    public static final String TABLE_AMPLITUDE = "sound";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE = "_amplitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME = "_time";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "memory.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement for location
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_LOC = "create table "
            + TABLE_LOCATION + "(" + COLUMN_LOCID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_LATITUDE
            + " double not null, "+ COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " double not null, "
            + COLUMN_TIME + " text not null, " + COLUMN_ACCURACY + " text not null, " +
            COLUMN_PROVIDER + " text not null " +");";

    // Database creation sql statement for picture
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PIC = "create table "
            + TABLE_PICTURE + "(" + COLUMN_PIC_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PIC_URL
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_LATITUDE
            + " double, "+ COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " double, "
            + COLUMN_TIME + " text, " + COLUMN_PIC_ACCURACY + " text " + ");";

    // Database creation sql statement for accelerometer
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ACCELEROMETER = "create table "
            + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER + "(" + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X
            + " float not null, " + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y
            + " float not null, "+ COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z + " float not null, "
            + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME + " text " +");";

    // Database creation sql statement for sound
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_AMPLITUDE = "create table "
            + TABLE_AMPLITUDE + "(" + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE
            + " double not null, " 
            + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME + " text " +");";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_LOC);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PIC);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ACCELEROMETER);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_AMPLITUDE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PICTURE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AMPLITUDE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

I dont find anything wrong in my tables. i checked for spaces.

The error i get is:

```
03-24 17:51:39.851: E/SQLiteLog(18574): (1) no such column: _url
03-24 17:51:39.855: W/dalvikvm(18574): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40eb0300)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-799
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _url (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _url, _latitude, _longitude, _time, _accuracy FROM picture
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at data.DatabaseInteraction.getAllPictures(DatabaseInteraction.java:191)
03-24 17:51:39.863: E/AndroidRuntime(18574):    at main.inSituApp.InSituApp$3.run(InSituApp.java:327)
```

I have a class that uses the database class to insert and query data to and from the database.

DatabaseInteraction.java

```
public class DatabaseInteraction {

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] locColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOCID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TIME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCURACY,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PROVIDER};

    private String[] picColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_URL, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_LATITUDE,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_LONGITUDE,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_TIME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_ACCURACY };

    private String[] accColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME };

    private String[] amplitudeColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME };

    public DatabaseInteraction(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public /*Loc*/ long  createLocation(double latitude, double longitude, long time,
            double accuracy, String provider) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TIME, time);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCURACY, accuracy);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PROVIDER, provider);
        open();
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION, null,
                values);
        close();
        return insertId;
        /*Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,
                locColumns,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOCID + " = " + insertId, null, null,
                null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Loc newLoc = cursorToLocation(cursor);
        cursor.close();

        return newLoc;*/
    }

    public long createPic(String url, double latitude, double longitude,
            long time) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_URL, url);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TIME, time);
        open();
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PICTURE, null,
                values);
        close();
        return insertId;
        /*Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PICTURE,
                picColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_ID + " = " + insertId,
                null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Pic newPic = cursorToPicture(cursor);
        cursor.close();

        return newPic;*/
    }

    public long createAccelerometer(float x, float y, float z,
            long time) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X, x);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y, y);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z, z);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME, time);
        open();
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ACCELEROMETER, null,
                values);
        close();
        return insertId;
    }

    public long createSound(double amplitude, long time) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE, amplitude);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME, time);

        open();
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_AMPLITUDE, null,
                values);
        close();
        return insertId;
    }

    public int deleteLocation(long id) {
        System.out.println("Location deleted with id: " + id);
        open();
        int value = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOCID + " = " + id, null);
        close();
        return value;
    }

    public int deletePic(long id){
        System.out.println("Picture deleted with id: " + id);
        open();
        int value = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PICTURE,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_ID + " = " + id, null);
        close();
        return value;
    }

    public int deleteAccelerometer(long id){
        System.out.println("Accelerometer deleted with id: " + id);
        open();
        int value = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ACCELEROMETER,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID + " = " + id, null);
        return value;
    }

    public int deleteSound(long id){
        System.out.println("Sound deleted with id: " + id);
        open();
        int value = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_AMPLITUDE,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID + " = " + id, null);
        close();
        return value;
    }

    public List<Loc> getAllLocations() {
        List<Loc> allLocations = new ArrayList<Loc>();
        open();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,
                locColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Loc oneLoc = cursorToLocation(cursor);
            allLocations.add(oneLoc);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return allLocations;
    }

    public List<Pic> getAllPictures() {
        List<Pic> allPictures = new ArrayList<Pic>();
        open();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PICTURE,
                picColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Pic onePic = cursorToPicture(cursor);
            allPictures.add(onePic);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return allPictures;
    }

    public List<Accelerometer> getAllAccelerometerValues() {
        List<Accelerometer> allAccelerometerValues = new ArrayList<Accelerometer>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ACCELEROMETER,
                accColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Accelerometer oneAcc = cursorToAccelerometer(cursor);
            allAccelerometerValues.add(oneAcc);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return allAccelerometerValues;
    }

    public List<Amplitude> getAllSoundAmpitudes() {
        List<Amplitude> allSoundAmplitudes = new ArrayList<Amplitude>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_AMPLITUDE,
                amplitudeColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Amplitude oneSound = cursorToAmplitude(cursor);
            allSoundAmplitudes.add(oneSound);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return allSoundAmplitudes;
    }

    private Loc cursorToLocation(Cursor cursor) {
        Loc location = new Loc();
        location.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(1));
        location.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(2));
        location.setTime(cursor.getLong(3));
        location.setAccuracy(cursor.getDouble(4));
        return location;
    }

    private Pic cursorToPicture(Cursor cursor) {
        Pic picture = new Pic();
        picture.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(1));
        picture.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(2));
        picture.setTime(cursor.getLong(3));
        return picture;
    }

    private Accelerometer cursorToAccelerometer(Cursor cursor) {
        Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();
        acc.setX(cursor.getFloat(1));
        acc.setY(cursor.getFloat(2));
        acc.setZ(cursor.getFloat(3));
        acc.setTime(cursor.getLong(4));
        return acc;
    }

    private Amplitude cursorToAmplitude(Cursor cursor) {
        Amplitude sound = new Amplitude();
        sound.setAmplitude(cursor.getDouble(1));
        sound.setTime(cursor.getLong(2));
        return sound;
    }

}
```

Please any hint is appreciated. ty very much in advance.

Comment: If you've recently added the column, uninstall your app so the old database file is deleted and then recreated.

Comment: Do you expect the column to be added during onUpgrade()? If yes, did you increase the version code in the manifest?

Comment: no the column is added as is. all columns are.

Comment: @laalto it worked. i had done it though. weird stuff.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: I understand why you said that. i just had done it and didnt worked. now it seems it did worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a different "picture" table structure, try deleting the current application,
then the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)` method will create the correct structure.

Comment: This is the correct answer although it was first provided by @laalto